# Is there a better way to compare Django model data with Django REST Framework response data?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API using Django REST Framework. I find myself writing a lot of duplicate code to test the API views, so I decided to try to write a mixin class that I can add to test cases to cut down on time spent typing out repetitive tests.

A really common test is that API response data match the objects stored in the database exactly. For example, one test might look like this:

```py
def test_list_object_response_returns_correct_json_data(self):
    objects = Object.objects.all()

    response = self.client.get(reverse('object-list'))
    response_json = response.json()

    for num, obj in enumerate(response_json):
        # convert JSON date strings to datetime objects
        obj_created = self.json_date_string_to_datetime(obj['created'])
        obj_updated = self.json_date_string_to_datetime(obj['updated'])

        self.assertEqual(obj['object_id'], str(objects[num].object_id))
        self.assertEqual(obj['name'], objects[num].name)
        self.assertEqual(obj_created, objects[num].created)
        self.assertEqual(obj_updated, objects[num].updated)
```

This passes, so I find myself using this pattern a lot to compare that a GET response matches all of the objects stored in the database.

I learned that generalizing this pattern is complicated. Here's what I've come up with so far as a mixin (that also passes in test with both positive and negative test cases):

```py
class GetMixin(BaseMixin):
    # BaseMixin has some more general methods that help with API tests
    # regardless of HTTP request method
    @classmethod
    def response_and_model_data_are_equal(cls, response, model):
        # first, verify that model is a Django model for .objects.all()
        if isinstance(model, ModelBase):
            instances = model.objects.all()

            # then, verify that the response data is a list rather than
            # a single item (e.g. a dict)
            if isinstance(response.data, list):
                # Assume the data match until they don't
                data_match = True

                for num, item in enumerate(response.data):
                    for field in cls.get_fields(item):
                        # if a datetime field comes up, convert the JSON
                        # timestamp string into a python datetime object
                        if isinstance(getattr(instances[num], field), datetime):
                            item_field_data = cls.json_date_string_to_datetime(item[field])
                        else:
                            item_field_data = item[field]

                        if item_field_data != getattr(instances[num], field):
                            data_match = False

                return data_match

            else:
                return False

        else:
            return False
```

This feels unnecessarily messy and difficult to maintain. Is there a more elegant way to generalize this sort of comparison?

It might be worth noting that I'd eventually like to use the same method to compare a response that contains a single item with a model instance so that I can use the same method regardless of whether I'm passing a list/Model combination or an item/instance combination.

**Update...**

After working through a few different test cases, here's where I landed. I ended up creating a `TestSerializer` that can accept any arbitrary model to help clean things up.

```py
    @classmethod
    def response_and_model_data_are_equal(cls, response, object_data_source):
        if isinstance(object_data_source, ModelBase):
            serializer_data = []

            instances = object_data_source.objects.all()

            for instance in instances:
                serializer = TestSerializer(instance, model=object_data_source)

                serializer_data.append(serializer.data)
        else:
            serializer = TestSerializer(object_data_source, model=type(object_data_source))
            serializer_data = serializer.data

        return response.data == serializer_data
```

Comment: *"A really **common test is** that API response data match the objects stored in the database exactly."* I don't think you need to write the same test again and agian.

Comment: You're probably right! But because serializers require that fields be explicitly outlined for each model, I'm writing tests assuming I've screwed something up (or will screw something up)

Comment: This may be a bit too meta for SO, but for whatever it's worth this approach saved me some headache when I added a new model with a ManyToMany relationship and neglected to update the serializer/views for the related model. As someone just learning, I'd be super interested to learn other approaches for hedging against this sort of thing aside from writing the same test again and again on a per-model/view basis.